# preg match not working on unicode letters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Preg match not producing any match with following code
The character  é at the beginning not working well with preg match

```
$name = array('éjaculation','précoce','fadfadf');

$names =array("{éjaculations précoce un {trouble|problème|souci|désordre} sexuel {assez|relativement|plutôt|très} {fréquent|commun|courant} qui {consiste en|est|se résume en} {l'incapacité|l'impossibilité} de {l'homme|l'individu|la personne} à {retenir|maîtriser|contrôler|retarder} {son éjaculation|son orgasme|son plaisir} {pour|durant} une {période|durée} {assez|suffisamment} {longue|prolongée} {afin de|de manière à|pour|de sorte à} {satisfaire|apporter le plus de satisfaction à|combler|faire plaisir à} sa {partenaire|femme|conjointe rand}|}",'teste');

preg_match("/\b".trim($name[1])."\b/ui",$names[0],$match);


print_r($match);
```

Comment: Word boundary `\b` doesn't work with unicode characters.

Comment: While `é` could be a spanish letter, your text is in french.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
preg_match("/(?<!\pL)".trim($name[0])."(?!\p{L})/ui", $names[0], $match);
```